# MySQL CHECK with regex

Tags: mysql, sql

```
alter table people add constraint people_chk_1 check (PhoneNum REGEXP '[0-9]{10}' );
insert into people values ('111111111','Maor','kobo',32.8,'0547768231');
insert into people values ('222222222','Din','kook',32.8,'058669493211');
```

why is the second insert statement is still inserting ??

Comment: Check constraints were not enforced on MySQL 5.7 or earlier.  In that case, you'd have to use a trigger instead.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is not anchored to the beginning and end of the string (unlike `like`).  So your expression is just looking for 10 digits in a row.

If you want exactly 10 digits:

```
PhoneNum REGEXP '^[0-9]{10}$'
```